# Find all parents as walking through a tree

Tags: clojure, zipper

I want to use `clojure.zip` to walk through this tree and print the node and its parent. I am having trouble getting the parent. For example the parent of `:e` is `:b`.

```
;;
;;     :a
;;     / \
;;   :b  :c
;;   /\    \
;; :d :e   :f
;;
(def example [:a [:b [:d] [:e]] [:c [:f]]])
(def z (zip/vector-zip example))
(def locs (take-while (complement zip/end?) (iterate zip/next z)))

(defn parent-of [loc]
  (when-let [parent-loc (-> loc zip/up zip/left)]
    (zip/node parent-loc)))

(defn visit-all []
  (doseq [loc locs]
    (let [node (zip/node loc)]
      (when (keyword? node)
        (println node "has parent" (parent-of loc))))))
```

This is the result:

```
:a has parent nil
:b has parent :a
:d has parent :b
:e has parent [:d]
:c has parent [:b [:d] [:e]]
:f has parent :c
```

I could keep improving the `parent-of` function - my next thought would be to go to the left-most node. There will be an algorithm that will return the correct answer from all locations - however going about it this way seems like quite a lot of work for a common requirement.

Is there a better approach I should be taking?

*Edit*
This question is not about `clojure.walk` or `Spector`. I am looking for an answer that uses `clojure.zip` and gives the parent as I defined it in the question, which is simply the keyword above the `loc`. So if the `loc` given to `parent-of` is `:f` I would expect it to return `:c`.

If someone can tell me, as a comment, that zippers are not really used anymore, and say `clojure.walk` or `Spector` is the current best practice way to go for navigating trees, then that would help.

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and outputs for the function you are trying to implement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure - walk with path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594375/clojure-walk-with-path)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `zip/left`? The parent of the node is exactly the node above it, not a node above it and to the left for some reason. Removing that is all you need to do.

Comment: I understand that technically speaking `zip/up` gives the parent. But the parent will always just be the enclosing vector. What I need (I believe) is the first element of this enclosing vector. That's why in my question I stated that the parent of `:e` is `:b`, even although technically speaking the parent of `:e` is `[:b [:d] [:e]]`.

Comment: So call `first` on the result of `(z/loc (z/up loc))`, if you want only the node's label and not also its structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own answer:

```
(defn parent-of [loc]
  (when-let [parent-loc (-> loc zip/up zip/up first)]
    (zip/node parent-loc)))
```

It gives the correct output in all cases:

```
:a has parent nil
:b has parent :a
:d has parent :b
:e has parent :b
:c has parent :a
:f has parent :c
```