# Clojure pre/post-walk with path from root

Tags: clojure

### What I know

I'm familiar with clojure.walk/prewalk and clojure.walk/postwalk

### What I want

I want something like clojure.walk/prewalk and clojure.walk/postwalk -- but I also want *the path required to get to the node* -- whereas prewalk/postwalk only gives me the nodes, w/o the actual path.

### Example

So if we had a structure

```
[ {:cat "Garfield", :dog "DogeCoin"} [:a :b {:site "so"}]]
```

then I want my function called with args:

```
[] [ {:cat "Garfield", :dog "DogeCoin"} [:a :b {:site "so"}]]

[0] {:cat "Garfield", :dog "DogeCoin"}

[1] [:a :b {:site "so"}]

[0 :cat] "Garfield"

...
```

### Question:

Is there a builtin for the above? where the processing function receives both the node and the path (from the root node) to the node)?

Thanks!

### Possible Solution

(based on what fl00r suggested)

```
(defn pathwalk [f cur-path node]
  (let [f1 #(pathwalk f (conj cur-path %1) %2)]
    (f cur-path node)
    (cond
      (map? node) (map #(apply f1 %) node)
      (or (vector? node) (list? node)) (keep-indexed f1 node))))
```

Comment: that's slightly different question, but maybe interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594375/clojure-walk-with-path

Comment: @fl00r : that was useful; I just wrote a solution based on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you also want 'pathwalk' to return something from function f similar to clojure.walk/prewalk and not rely on side-effect?  E.g.

```
(prewalk #(if (= :a %) :c %) [:a :b])
=>
[:c :b]
```

If yes, then you can do this:

```
(defn pathwalk [f path e]
  (let [e' (f path e)]
    (cond
      (map? e')  (->> e'
                      (map (fn [[k x]] [k (pathwalk f (conj path k) x)]))
                      (into (empty e')))
      (coll? e') (->> e'
                      (map-indexed (fn [i x] (pathwalk f (conj path i) x)))
                      (into (empty e')))
      :else      e')))
```

Here is a test run:

```
(pathwalk #(do
             (println %1 %2)
             (if (= :a %2)
               :c
               %2))
          []
          [ {:cat "Garfield", :dog "DogeCoin"} [:a :b {:site "so"}]])
```

it will print:

```
[] [{:cat Garfield, :dog DogeCoin} [:a :b {:site so}]]
[0] {:cat Garfield, :dog DogeCoin}
[0 :cat] Garfield
[0 :dog] DogeCoin
[1] [:a :b {:site so}]
[1 0] :a
[1 1] :b
[1 2] {:site so}
[1 2 :site] so
```

and below data will be returned from the function:

```
[{:cat "Garfield", :dog "DogeCoin"} [:c :b {:site "so"}]]
```

Comment: For this particular example, the goal was side effects (i.e. building a flattened [[path value]] list), but yes, you're right, in general, there should also be support for pure f's. Thanks!